How to improve detection of multiple different images on captured screen with OpenCV
I am trying to automate Google Chrome Dino game in order to do that I cropped the images of objects to dodge such as small cacti, big cacti, bird (pterodactyl) in both day and night state (game has alternating day and night cycle) and by using OpenCV matchTemplate function I am able to locate the objects by looping throughout the dictionary of objects in question.
The way my program works in while loop:

Capture screen with area in front of the dino

Loop through objects I want to detect and detect with with cs2.matchTemplate

When detected object x coordinate is within distance threshold the dino jumps


The problem is, I would like to improve the performance of the object detection - as it is now image gives 15 FPS and I want the Dino to jump as soon as object is in the distance threshold. As it is now Dino is able to dodge some objects however is far from perfect - even at the beginning of the game when it is relatively slow.
This is main script:
def main_script():

    # Local variables
    loop_time = 0.00001
    fps_list = []
    action_threshold = 280
    dodge_objects = {
        'big_cacti_day': GameObject(find_img('big_cacti_day.png')),
        'big_cacti_night': GameObject(find_img('big_cacti_night.png')),
        'bird_day': GameObject(find_img('bird_day.png')),
        'bird_night': GameObject(find_img('bird_night.png')),
        'small_cacti_day': GameObject(find_img('small_cacti_day.png')),
        'small_cacti_night': GameObject(find_img('small_cacti_night.png')),
    }
    # Start the game
    jump(actions)
    
    # Game loop
    with mss.mss() as sct:
        monitor = {"top": 600, "left": 250, "width": 550, "height": 150}
        while 1:
            # FPS print for testing
            print_fps(fps_list, loop_time)
            loop_time = time.time()

            # Update game screen
            img = numpy.array(sct.grab(monitor))
            game_screen = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

            for key in dodge_objects:
                dodge_object = dodge_objects[key]
                if dodge_object.match(game_screen):
                    dodge_object_left_x = dodge_object.location[0][0]
                    cv2.rectangle(game_screen, dodge_object.location[0], dodge_object.location[1], (0,0,255), 2)

                    # Action
                    if dodge_object_left_x < action_threshold:
                        print(key, 'x:', dodge_object_left_x, 'y:', dodge_object_left_y)
                        jump(actions)

            # Show recorded region
            cv2.imshow('screen', game_screen)
            if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
                break

This is GameObject class
import cv2

class GameObject:

    location = None
    
    def __init__(self, path):
        img = cv2.imread(path, 0)
        self.img = img
        self.width = img.shape[1]
        self.height = img.shape[0]


    def match(self, screen):
        res = cv2.matchTemplate(screen, self.img, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
        minVal, maxVal, minLoc, maxLoc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)
        startLoc = maxLoc
        endLoc = (startLoc[0] + self.width, startLoc[1] + self.height)

        if maxVal > 0.8:
            self.location = (startLoc, endLoc)
            return True
        else:
            self.location = None
            return False


I've tried using different screen capturing libraries such as dxcam, win32api, pyautogui, PIL, it seems the best performance is what mss library gives.

I've tried cropping the region of interest with mss that selects small area 550x150 in front of Dino, it did improve performance but is still not enough

I've tried cropping images of objects to dodge to the smallest possible:


     
It seems that both using python loop and cv2.matchTemplate are the two major components that are slowing my script - with the for loop section commented out I am getting ~27 fps
If there are more techniques I can implement to improve performance of my code I would love to hear about them.
EDIT:
I've used profiler to estimate the time taken for my code, I've excluded cv2.waitKey as advised, here is how I've done it:

at the beginning of main_script()

    pr = cProfile.Profile()
    pr.enable()
    start_time = time.perf_counter()


in while loop:

            current_time = time.perf_counter()
            elapsed_time = current_time - start_time
            if elapsed_time > 60:
                break


after 60 seconds passed I get the results

        pr.disable()
        ps = pstats.Stats(pr).sort_stats(pstats.SortKey.TIME)
        ps.print_stats()


here are the first ~30 rows of profiling results

         39251 function calls (39248 primitive calls) in 59.879 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
     1114   34.266    0.031   34.288    0.031 C:\Users\kubas\Desktop\100 day python coding\myenv\Lib\site-packages\mss\windows.py:203(_grab_impl)
     6684   16.933    0.003   16.933    0.003 {matchTemplate}
      152    7.638    0.050    7.638    0.050 {built-in method time.sleep}
     1114    0.277    0.000    0.285    0.000 {built-in method numpy.array}
     1114    0.245    0.000    0.245    0.000 {imshow}
     6684    0.205    0.000    0.205    0.000 {minMaxLoc}
     1114    0.144    0.000    0.144    0.000 {cvtColor}
       75    0.067    0.001    0.067    0.001 {built-in method builtins.print}
     6684    0.032    0.000   17.170    0.003 c:\Users\kubas\Desktop\100 day python coding\test\test\game_object.py:14(match)
     1114    0.013    0.000    0.021    0.000 C:\Users\kubas\Desktop\100 day python coding\myenv\Lib\site-packages\mss\screenshot.py:24(__init__)
     1114    0.012    0.000   34.305    0.031 C:\Users\kubas\Desktop\100 day python coding\myenv\Lib\site-packages\mss\base.py:69(grab)
       76    0.010    0.000    0.011    0.000 C:\Users\kubas\Desktop\100 day python coding\myenv\Lib\site-packages\pyautogui\_pyautogui_win.py:250(_keyDown)
     1114    0.006    0.000    0.008    0.000 C:\Users\kubas\Desktop\100 day python coding\myenv\Lib\site-packages\mss\screenshot.py:41(__array_interface__)
       76    0.006    0.000    0.006    0.000 C:\Users\kubas\Desktop\100 day python coding\myenv\Lib\site-packages\pyautogui\_pyautogui_win.py:295(_keyUp)
     2382    0.004    0.000    0.004    0.000 {built-in method __new__ of type object at 0x00007FFB757B13D0}
     1370    0.003    0.000    0.003    0.000 {built-in method builtins.isinstance}
      197    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 {rectangle}
      152    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 C:\Users\kubas\Desktop\100 day python coding\myenv\Lib\site-packages\pyautogui\_pyautogui_win.py:335(_position)
     1114    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 C:\Users\kubas\Desktop\100 day python coding\myenv\Lib\site-packages\mss\screenshot.py:68(height)
     1114    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 {method '__exit__' of '_thread.lock' objects}
        6    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {imread}
     1116    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {built-in method time.perf_counter}
       76    0.001    0.000    0.019    0.000 C:\Users\kubas\Desktop\100 day python coding\myenv\Lib\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py:1581(press)
       12    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {built-in method nt._getfinalpathname}
      152    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 C:\Users\kubas\Desktop\100 day python coding\myenv\Lib\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py:526(isShiftCharacter)
        1    0.001    0.001    0.001    0.001 C:\Users\kubas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py:49(create_string_buffer)
      152    0.001    0.000    0.003    0.000 C:\Users\kubas\Desktop\100 day python coding\myenv\Lib\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py:752(position)
       76    0.001    0.000    7.661    0.101 C:\Users\kubas\Desktop\100 day python coding\myenv\Lib\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py:591(wrapper)
     1114    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 C:\Users\kubas\Desktop\100 day python coding\myenv\Lib\site-packages\mss\screenshot.py:113(width)
       76    0.000    0.000    7.661    0.101 c:\Users\kubas\Desktop\100 day python coding\test\test\main.py:8(jump)
      152    0.000    0.000    0.004    0.000 C:\Users\kubas\Desktop\100 day python coding\myenv\Lib\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py:1732(failSafeCheck)
       76    0.000    0.000    7.638    0.100 C:\Users\kubas\Desktop\100 day python coding\myenv\Lib\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py:631(_handlePause)

EDIT -> full code of main.py after introducing profiling:
import os, cv2, mss, numpy, pyautogui, numpy as np, time
from game_object import GameObject
import cProfile, pstats

def find_img(name):
    return os.path.join(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'img_game'), name)

def jump():
    pyautogui.press('space')

def main_script(): 
    pr = cProfile.Profile()
    pr.enable()
    start_time = time.perf_counter()

    # Local variables
    loop_time = 0.00001
    fps_list = []
    action_threshold = 280
    dodge_objects = {
        'big_cacti_day': GameObject(find_img('big_cacti_day.png')),
        'big_cacti_night': GameObject(find_img('big_cacti_night.png')), 
        'bird_day': GameObject(find_img('bird_day.png')),
        'bird_night': GameObject(find_img('bird_night.png')),
        'small_cacti_day': GameObject(find_img('small_cacti_day.png')),
        'small_cacti_night': GameObject(find_img('small_cacti_night.png')),
    } 
    
    # Start the game
    jump() 
    
    # Game loop
    with mss.mss() as sct:
        monitor = {"top": 600, "left": 250, "width": 550, "height": 150}

        while 1:
            current_time = time.perf_counter()
            elapsed_time = current_time - start_time
            if elapsed_time > 60:
                break

            # Update game screen
            img = numpy.array(sct.grab(monitor))
            game_screen = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

            # Detection
            for key in dodge_objects:
                dodge_object = dodge_objects[key]
                if dodge_object.match(game_screen):
                    dodge_object_left_x = dodge_object.location[0][0]
                    cv2.rectangle(game_screen, dodge_object.location[0], dodge_object.location[1], (0,0,255), 2)

                    # Action
                    if dodge_object_left_x < action_threshold:
                        print(key, 'x:', dodge_object_left_x)
                        jump()


            # Show recorded region - deleted waitkey
            cv2.imshow('screen', img)


        pr.disable()
        ps = pstats.Stats(pr).sort_stats(pstats.SortKey.TIME)
        ps.print_stats()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_script()


measure first. find out where the time is spent. "it seems" isn't good enough. you need to have numbers.

@ChristophRackwitz with whole section of for loop that takes care of detection and actions i am getting ~15 fps, with this section commented out I get ~27fps

that's not what I asked for. let me be more specific. use a profiler. find out the time taken for every single line. -- without the for-loop, it still only runs at 27 fps? there is more potential -- your measurements may be wrong. time.time() has fairly low resolution, can be as bad as ~16 ms. always use time.perf_counter(). exclude the waitKey() from that and measure it separately. it too "aligns" to the OS scheduler's ticking (upto 16 ms).

@ChristophRackwitz Hi, I've used profiler to estimate the time taken for my code, I've excluded cv2.waitKey as advised. It was my first time using it so I've wrote how I've used it. Please let me know what do you think.

ok so matchTemplate does appear to take significant time, but so do other parts. I see pyautogui and time.sleep() in the profile, but not in your code.

@ChristophRackwitz I've provided full main.py in 2nd edit, game_object.py was untouched - pyautogui is responsible for hitting space when dino gets close to the object to dodge, as for time.sleep method - I don't know how it got there, maybe due to some of libraries using it?

The screenshot capture seems to be by far the biggest bottleneck, I'd consider running that asynchronously.

I would also make GameObject internally cache the array holding the result of cv2.matchTemplate (pre-allocate it, and specifying the destination argument). No need to constantly allocate new arrays only to immediately throw them away (allocations are not free). You could do that in few more places too, but here it would have the largest impact.

@DanMašek by running asynchronously do you mean that I should use threading?

Good question. Looking at the implementation of mss, it's pure Python, invoking WinAPI calls using ctypes. I'm guessing it's either the BitBlt or GetDIBits that's taking most of the time, and from what I can find ctypes will release the GIL during the function call. So I'd say yes, try threading. You'll still have similar latency between capture and result, but the overall throughput should increase.

I think it's yet too early to recommend threading or preallocating. threading is probably way over OP's head. preallocating won't save all that much. it's a few allocations per second at most. I'd have to run this myself to figure out where time actually goes. maybe this simply runs on a very slow computer and is so slow because of that.

@ChristophRackwitz True. Looking at the game, it seems like template matching is an overkill. Free terrain generally has at most 2 black pixels (before scaling up) per column. Obstacles have more. Vertical projection to detect column groups with obstacles. Horizontal projection on those to determine whether to duck or jump.

Anyway, I'd also give a shot at profiling it with Scalene, that seems to handle libraries with native code much better.

I agree, this doesn't need template matching or object detection. just run a scan line across the image and detect the cactii that way. cheap as dirt. your approach of masking and checking vertically sounds even more robust.

I just copied all that code into a file to run it myself. I don't see any time.sleep() here. I commented out the pyautogui.press() call, so maybe that has been spamming space keys in your system. it's likely to contain some sleep so the keydown and keyup have some separation -- I am getting ~23 fps on my 12 year old computer. it's even detecting the cacti but it does spam the space key for every detection within the "action threshold", not just once

I added some custom perfcounter difference summing. matching appears to take ~70% of the total loop time. capturing is at ~25%. cvtColor almost takes nothing, imshow takes the remaining ~5-15% (probably another cvtcolor and some sleep in there, pollkey is a little faster)

since that web page scales to the viewport's width, you'll have a lot of trouble with matchTemplate anyway.

@ChristophRackwitz what would be the solution to optimize my code in this case? I really would love to learn how to do a project like that with OpenCV and know how to improve its performance. Is that even possible with match template method?

It just that I would like to make similar projects like this maybe with higher resolutions, I agree that I can just scan one line with 1 pixel height and ~400 pixel in width and detect singular black pixels and make decision on it but probably in future i would love to do similar projects that would require higher resolution and for that I need to know how can I optimalize the script
